# Style.css file in WordPress child theme doesn't work

Tags: php, css, wordpress, themes

I am using for the first time a child theme on WordPress and I noticed that despite having inserted the customizations in the style.css of the child they are not actually visible in the front-end.

In the child's functions.php the content is this:

```
function kerge_child_theme_enqueue_styles() {

$parent_style = 'parent-style';

wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
array( $parent_style ),
wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'kerge_child_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

The child theme is up and running.

Some suggestions?

Comment: Your code looks ok so it's difficult to tell what could be causing the problem. All we can do if give you some pointers on things that can potentially cause this issue: Have you confirmed if the child stylesheet is getting included i.e. is it appearing in the html source of the pages? Does the css file exist (basic but always worth checking!)? Could the issue be to do with caching (browser caching, server caching or plugins?)

Answer (score 0):

As I know you shouldn't include parent or child styles.
You just need to create style.css in the child theme and activate this child theme in settings. That's all.

Or create additional style.css in the CSS folder and enqueue it:

```
// enqueue parent styles
wp_enqueue_style('chld_thm_parent', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'style.css', []);

// enqueue child styles
wp_enqueue_style('chld_thm_parent_additonal_styles', trailingslashit(get_stylesheet_directory_uri()) . 'css/style.css', [], time());
```